# PHP Multicurl Works for a while then gives a 500 error on Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, curl, shared

Alright, so I have a script that uses a rolling curl for multiple requests. The past two days, it works for a couple times, but then eventually it starts providing a 500 error. I try a regular curl_init and that works, so I know I'm getting connection with the site I'm connecting too. And if I wait for tomorrow it will work again. So I imagine there is some leak or something going on. I can't figure out how to check 500 errors on Godaddy. But is there a way I can check curl to see what the issue is or stop it from the infinite loop. Because it's not connecting. And just to clarify the very same script works at first, but after a certain number of tries, it stops.

```
while (($execrun = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $running)) == 
CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) {
        ;
}

if ($execrun != CURLM_OK) {
        break;
}   

//not entering this loop
while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->multi_handle)) {

}
```

Edit: I'm doing about 30 requests at a time. It works very fast and works for like the first 4-5 times I load the script. But then eventually it will just stop and I'll have to wait for the next day. Here's the while loop where the only occurrences of closing the handles are. I've never ran in to this problem before. Have no clue where to look. It just won't connect to the website and enter this loop.

```
        while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->multi_handle)) {

        $ch = $info['handle'];
        $ch_array_key = (int)$ch;


        if (!isset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key])) {
            die("Error - handle wasn't found in requests: '$ch' in ".
                print_r($this->outstanding_requests, true));
        }

        $request = $this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key];
        $url = $request['url'];

        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); 
        $callback = $this->curl['CALLBACK'];  

        $user_data = $request['user_data'];

        if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200)
        {
            call_user_func($callback, $content, $url, $ch, $user_data, $user_data);
            unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);

            curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        else
        {
            //unset the outstanding request so it doesn't get stuck in a loop
            unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);
            curl_close($ch);                

            //these come back as 0's, so not found. Restart the request
            self::startRequest($url);   
        }
        //self::msg('USER END');
    }
```

Comment: In programming, something that doesn't change doesn't just break and work again without a valid reason (such as loosing internet connection). Perhaps *godaddy* is blocking your requests because they have a valid reason to do so?

Comment: Well of course. I have no clue what is causing it. The curl_init works by itself and the multi curl script works for the first couple times using it, but then eventually it will start throwing the 500 error and I'll have to wait for the next day. So not sure if there is a leak or what is going on to stop the process from working. There are no errors showing with curl, just nothing is returning and causing the curl_multi_info_read to never be called.

Comment: A clue might be is that godaddy wants to prevent a DDOS attack, in essence that's what a `curl_muti_exec()` can do. Perhaps you should request **all** the data with 1 `exec()`?

Comment: Are you closing your individual curl handles? Are you calling `curl_multi_remove_handle()` on individual handles as they are completed?  Show us all your relevant code.  How many requests are you making, 10s, 100s, 1000s?  Are you pausing between requests?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I edited my initial post with additional information. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see the 500 error?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It just shows the query string, the url, then the number 500 after about 2 minutes. When it works the first couple times it takes less than 3 seconds.

Comment: I have been playing with your code and got it to work locally ...  None the code you've shown would `shows the query string, the url, then the number 500` (I tested against http://httpstat.us/500)?  There must be more you are not showing us, and it seems that might be relevant, as that's where it is failing.  Please try to create [a minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.  However, my guess is you are simply being firewalled by DOS-ing the target.  Try grabbing 5 at a time instead of 30, put some `sleep(1)` in your loops, be polite.